# Why doesn't Ubuntu see my PCI card on installs?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.10

Whether booting from a bootable thumbdrive or dvd, any version of Ubuntu I try I just get a black screen. I have to get a VGA monitor and go into bios and tell it to use onboard graphics, then install the ubuntu flavor I want to  use, then install NVIDIA drivers (sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates), then reboot and go back into bios and choose PCI graphics and then it's back to normal.

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12

05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] [10de:0622] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: BFG Tech Device [19f1:08fe]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
        Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at fa000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at dc00 [size=128]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at fea80000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Is there anything I can do to use a bootable thumbdrive and just do a normal install without changing monitors?

Comment: Have you tried booting from an alternate CD? 
http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent
http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-i386.iso.torrent

Comment: Is this LTS only or can I do the 14.10? Going back to Xubuntu.  I just use the common 64 bit download and it's just blackscreen with no prompts or anything. Does alternate give me terminal prompts and a GUI for install?

Comment: Can't really answer these, I just know that many times when I had issues with normal CD the alternate one worked fine. There is installer there also (wizard like). http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/

Comment: Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @Sneetsher  - I didn't see this in my search. This sight is so vast that searching is hard unless you get the right verbage.  I just finished using mbiber suggestion, just I would rather have a clean install for 14.10 than updating.  For the record the alternate cd did work.  The first boot after install did not work but I went into safe mode and even tho I did not do anything I was able to boot up normally. It's an early Sunday afternoon so I'll give the other option a try.

Comment: @Sneetsher Thanks for the input, but the only one that came close was #2 in the accepted answer and that didn't work for me, trying all three changes suggested.  All others seemed to cover systems with the operating system already loaded and correcting problems after install or at least being able to install.

Comment: @mbiber if you post your response as an answer I will be more than happy to mark it as the answer I was looking for.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried booting from an alternate CD? Download links: [64-bit version](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) and [32-bit version](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-i386.iso.torrent)

I know that many times when I had issues with normal CD the alternate one worked fine. There is installer there also (wizard like). Read about it here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04